# Regular expression prints one out of two in matching pattern

Tags: php, regex

Hey guys, question about regex in PHP!

For the given pattern, kinda like a shell terminal syntax:

```
application>function -arg1 value -arg2 value -arg3 value -arg4 value
```

I want to parse the arguments. This is my regex code

```
$command=' -arg1 value -arg2 value -arg3 value -arg4 value ';

// note the string begins by a space character and ends by a space character
// now i'm trying to parse arguments

$cmd->arguments=new \stdClass();

preg_replace('`\s-(.*)\s([a-zA-Z0-9-_]*)\s`Ue',
'$cmd->arguments->$1="$2";',$command);

// this regex will pick one matching out of two and returns

$cmd->arguments=stdClass(

    [arg1]=>value,
    [arg3]=>value

)
```

arg2 and arg4 are skipped. Any idea why? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: You have a space `\s` both at the start and at the end of your regex, so after the first match `arg1`, the first occurrence of `\s-` is at `arg3` because the space you are searching for before `arg2` has already been matched at the end of the first match.

It also might be easier to just `trim()` the string and then `split()` / `explode()` it at the spaces.

**Edit:** By the way, removing the `\s` at the end should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use getopt() http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/21/2/4

Comment: This may be a good alternative, but why recommend another approach?  All OP asked for was why regex doesn't work -- that does not mean that this is the exact way it was intended to be used.  There may be other valid reasons for doing it this way, which were hidden when the test case was written.

Comment: Indeed. I assumed only his example. Which would be very easy achievable with getopt().

Comment: actually i am working with a code from somebody else and its syntax is similar to a shell syntax yet different on some occasions. Thanks though!

Comment: Obsolete link? :)

Answer (score 0):

As jeroen said, your specific issue is the `\s` at the beginning and end of your regex.

It is easy to rewrite this regex so that the spaces are not needed at all, except in between the `arg` and `value`. Consider this regex:

```
-(.*?)\s+([a-zA-Z0-9-_]*)
```

Matches:

```
    -arg1 value -arg2 value -arg3 value  -arg4  value  //spaces before and between...
-arg1 value    -arg2 value -arg3 value   -arg4    value //no lead spaces...
```